# Bivariate normal probability of being inside ellipse

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, geometry, ellipse

> Assume that $\mathbf{X}$ is a bivariate normal random variable $$\mathbf{\mu} = E\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \  \text{and} \ \Sigma = Cov \ \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> What is the probability that $\mathbf{X}$ falls within the elipse corresponding to $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}) = 4.6 ?$

[image]

So Im assuming I need to calculate the probability of $x_1$ lying between $x_1$ min and $x_1$ max, and likewise for $x_2$? However Im not sure how to do this calculation seeing as the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not independent. It also seems like the endpoints of the ellipse do not match my calculations. I believe the ellipse should have half axe lengths $\sqrt{\lambda_i b}$ and its centered at $\mathbf{\mu}$. So according to my calculations $x_1$ should lie between -4.28 and +4.28 which seems incorrect from graphical inspection.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3543987/321264). Choose where you want to ask.

Comment: Hint: Just proof that $\Sigma^{-1/2}(X-\mu) \sim \mathcal{MVN}(0,I)$, so that $(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)$ have a chi-sqaured ditribution.

Comment: See our posts on [Mahalanobis distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mahalanobis+distance+score%3A2).